# How can I use ARCore and OpenGL without Sceneform for making ar measurement app android?

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, arcore, measurement

Basically I want to create an AR Measurement app for android. I already have code with using sceneform but these is requirement to use opengl and arcore instead of using sceneform.

So my question is is it possible to do so and anyone else here provide some feedback on it?